# typescript counting duplicates in array and sorting the result by the count of each item

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array which is populated based on the values pulled in from an api call.
the array would be having values like this

```
["9777", "9777", "2.4", "9777", "2.4", "2.4", "9777", "2.4", "2.4", "9777", "9777", "2.4", "2.4", "2.4"]
```

What I am trying to do is get the count of the occurences of each item in the array and sort it descending based on the count.

I did this which I got it from stackoverflow:

```
data.forEach(function (x) {
  counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1;
});
```

It works, but it gives weird results which makes it difficult to extract the value from the result.
here are the results:
[image]

Comment: How are the results weird? What results do you want?

Comment: How do I extract the item name and then the count of that item, also how do i sort it based on the count

Comment: It sounds like you want an object, which isn't sortable, however, an array of objects is sortable.

Comment: Okay, would you be able to give me an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is using the function `reduce` to count and create an object with the counts and then use the function `sort`.

If you want to extract a specific object by the "name", you can use the function `find`:

```js
let array = ["9777", "9777", "2.4", "9777", "2.4", "2.4", "9777", "2.4", "2.4", "9777", "9777", "2.4", "2.4", "2.4"],
    counts = Object.values(array.reduce((a, c) => {
      (a[c] || (a[c] = {name: c, count: 0})).count += 1;
      return a;
    }, {})).sort(({count: ac}, {count: bc}) => bc - ac),
    target = "2.4",
    found = counts.find(({name}) => name === target);

console.log(counts);
console.log(found);
console.log(found.count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hello @ele Thanks for the code, the reduce works perfectly, but the sorting it should be on the results of the reduce operation. For e.g if the item "2.4" is more than "9777" in the array then the the item item "2.4" should be the first item on the sorted array with its count as well.

Comment: It is working right now, now how do i extract the item name and the count of that item for the view. I did counts[0] gave me {2.4: 8}. How to extract just 2.4 and then its count by itself

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do would be to get a unique list of items, then loop through that list to add to the final result.

Once the list is generated, we can sort the list using the key `count` that we created from the previous action.

```js
const items = ["9777", "9777", "2.4", "9777", "2.4", "2.4", "9777", "2.4", "2.4", "9777", "9777", "2.4", "2.4", "2.4"];

// A place to store the results
const result = [];

// Create a unique list of items to loop over
// Add each item to the result list
[...new Set(items)].forEach(item => result.push({
  key: item,
  // Get the count of items of the current type
  count: items.filter(i => i == item).length
}));

// Sort the array from highest to lowest
result.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks @Get Off My Lawn. Just wondering what would be [...new Set, it gives me a squiggly.

Comment: That is the `es6` way of creating a unique list of items.

Comment: your `tsconfig.json` file must have a `target` of `es6` or `es2015` or greater.

Comment: Si I just need to change that there, I do see it as "target":es5

Comment: I change it to es6 on tsconfig.json, all the squigglies are gone, but I do get a compile error on console. I have uploaded the pic of the error, please check.

Comment: I am not using slice, so there must be an error somewhere else in the code.

Comment: But when I comment out your code , it doesn't show that error.

Comment: It is possible that code using the results doesn't like the format

Comment: Oh is it, How do i do the [..new] part in es5